# Nodemailer no refresh token or refresh handler callback is set error

Tags: email, oauth-2.0, oauth, nodemailer

The email sending works within the first day of getting the refresh token. However it always fails a few days later and it will work again when i regenerate a new refresh token in OAuth 2.0 playground.

I have already put in the refresh token here which is obtained from OAuth playground!

```
const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  CLIENT_ID,
  CLIENT_SECRET,
  REDIRECT_URI
);

oAuth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN });

google.options({ auth: oAuth2Client }); // Apply the settings globally
```

Answer (score 0):

First off if you are creating the refresh token via the OAuth 2.0 playground using the default credetinals the tokens are only going to last a few days at most OAuth 2.0 playground is only meant for testing it should not be something you should be relying upon.

Second if you are using your own client id and client secret same goes.  OAuth 2.0 playground. should not be used for applications its just for testing you should fix your code sot hat you request or own refresh token and access token.

That being said if your application is still in testing the refresh tokens only last seven days and then they will be revoked.

[image]

Your application should be able to handle the refresh tokens expiring and request a new one of the user.

Comment: Does this mean that the tutorial listed below only allows for temporary sending of emails?

https://newbedev.com/nodemailer-gmail-what-exactly-is-a-refresh-token-and-how-do-i-get-one

Comment: That example appears to be using the second option.  it tells you how to create the client id and secret so you are creating your own.   But they are still going to last max a week if your project is in testing.   Also with the Gmail api if the user changes their password its also going to revoke your token.

Comment: Do I still have to handle the refresh token expiration after setting the application to production mode? I am confused by the refresh token handling as I do not know how to request a new one and call setCredentials with it.

Comment: You should, there are some cases where the refresh token will expire you should always prompt the user for authorization again if it does expire.